# Java: Comparing three different fields in order. Like an SQL Database

Tags: java, sql, database

For example, in "SQL I have a SELECT * FROM db ORDER by first, middle, last ASC" and the output would sort in order by the first name first then the middle name the last name right? How can I have a comparable function with the same output in Java? Hope you understand what I meant here. Thank you.

I have the following sample;

```
public static final Comparator<Person> NameCompare = new Comparator<Person>()
{
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o2.first().compareTo(o1.first()) == 0 ? o2.first().compareTo(o1.first()) : o2.middle().compareTo(o1.middle()) == 0 ? o2.middle().compareTo(o1.last()) : o2.property().compareTo(o1.last());
    }
};
```

EDIT:
Sample Sorted Order:

1. Abc Bcd Efg
2. Abc Def Ghi
3. Cde Fgh Ijk
4. Cde Fgh Lmn
5. Hij Ijk Lmn
6. Zee Why Bee

Comment: so what's your problem? You dunno how to sort a collection with a Comparator? Or your comparator is not working properly?

Comment: Yeah my comparator is not working properly when sorting more than 2 objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Java 8, you can do:

```
Comparator<Person> comp = Comparator.comparing(Person::getFirst)
                                .thenComparing(Person::getMiddle)
                                .thenComparing(Person::getLast);
```

and to sort a list:

```
List<Person> people = ...;
people.sort(comp);
```

Comment: Oh, this is a good choice, very easy and simple to understand. I didn't know that java 8 allowed this. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public static final Comparator<Person> NameCompare = new Comparator<Person>()
    {
       public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        int i = o1.first.compareTo(o2.first);
        if (i != 0) return i;

        i = o1.middle.compareTo(o2.middle);
        if (i != 0) return i;

        return o1.last.compareTo(o2.last);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an alternative if you are using JDK < 8.

Libraries like Guava and Apache Commons Lang provides utility to make chaining compare methods easier (Code extracted directly from their documentations, just to give you an idea.  You will need a little twist to use it in `Comparator`.):

Guava

```
public int compareTo(Foo that) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
        .compare(this.aString, that.aString)
        .compare(this.anInt, that.anInt)
        .compare(this.anEnum, that.anEnum, Ordering.natural().nullsLast())
        .result();
}
```

Apache Commons Lang 2/3

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    MyClass myClass = (MyClass) o;
    return new CompareToBuilder()
       .appendSuper(super.compareTo(o)
       .append(this.field1, myClass.field1)
       .append(this.field2, myClass.field2)
       .append(this.field3, myClass.field3)
       .toComparison();
}
```